# karma not found from maven after re-install

Tags: linux, node.js, karma-runner

I asked an earlier question at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615367/how-to-make-npm-re-set-path-for-half-installed-modules) , but I think the problem is slightly different now.

After I did "npm install -g", I ran my build, but it fails with the following:

```
karma start /media/sf_Users/.../src/test/webapp/js/karma.conf.js --browsers PhantomJS --reporters dots,junit,coverage --single-run --no-auto-watch --colors false

module.js:340 
throw err; 
      ^ 
Error: Cannot find module '/home/<mylogin>/bin/node_modules/karma/bin/karma' 
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) 
at startup (node.js:119:16) 
at node.js:906:3
```

As it describes, there is no "node_modules" folder in my $HOME/bin folder.

The output from "npm install -g" might be helpful, and that is:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.2.1

> phantomjs@1.9.12 install /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1414523124621/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Removing /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1414523124621
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
npm WARN engine coffee-script-redux@2.0.0-beta4: wanted: {"node":"0.6.x || 0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.32","npm":"1.4.28"})

> ws@0.4.32 install /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/michaelficarra/cscodegen.git Initialized empty Git repository in /home/<myname>/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-michaelficarra-cscodegen-git-c4b567f3/
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/michaelficarra/cscodegen.git 
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/michaelficarra/cscodegen.git github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/michaelficarra/cscodegen.git fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing cscodegen@git://github.com/michaelficarra/cscodegen.git#73fd7202ac086c26f18c9d56f025b18b3c6f5383
<myname>@0.0.0 /home/<myname>/frameworks/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/<myname>
├── karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.5
├── karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3
├── karma-script-launcher@0.1.0
├── karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0
├── karma-jasmine@0.1.5
├── karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 (coffee-script@1.7.1)
├── requirejs@2.1.15
├── karma-requirejs@0.2.2
├── karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 (phantomjs@1.9.12)
├── karma@0.10.10 (di@0.0.1, rimraf@2.1.4, colors@0.6.0-1, graceful-fs@1.2.3, mime@1.2.11, q@0.9.7, minimatch@0.2.14, glob@3.1.21, optimist@0.3.7, chokidar@0.8.4, coffee-script@1.6.3, log4js@0.6.21, lodash@1.1.1, connect@2.8.8, http-proxy@0.10.4, useragent@2.0.10, socket.io@0.9.17)
└── karma-coverage@0.1.5 (dateformat@1.0.8, istanbul@0.1.46, ibrik@1.0.1)
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Hm, am I missing something? Where does maven come into play here?

Comment: I'm running karma from maven with the "maven-karma-plugin".  Note that this works fine on my Windows box with Cygwin, I'm just having trouble with the linux environment looking at my Windows FS.

Comment: I appear to be getting closer.  I made sure that none of the old "node_modules" trees existed and did "npm install -g".  I then manually added "$NODEJS_HOME/lib/node_modules/<myuid>node_modules/karma/bin" to my path.  It's now starting Karma and PhantomJS, but PhantomJS fails to get any "messages", so it stops.  I'll ask about this in a separate posting.